# Why does Zend_Http_Response divide status codes by 100

Tags: php, http, zend-framework

I've been seeing developers pattern after some code in Zend and I'm trying to figure out why Zend might have implemented http response code checking this way:

```
/**
 * Check whether the response in successful
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isSuccessful()
{
    $restype = floor($this->code / 100);
    if ($restype == 2 || $restype == 1) { // Shouldn't 3xx count as success as well ???
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Specifically, why would they do that instead of

```
public function isSuccessful()
{
    return $this->code >= 100 && $this->code < 300
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the floor and the / 100 spend CPU cycles needlessly?

Comment: That statement is clearly preemptive optimization, try not to think like that... Unless you are doing a 1 billion loop with a floor thats useless, don't take it into account. Floor is a function that is definitely extremely fast compared to userland code...

Comment: i'm no expert but a compiler should optimize a `/int` into a shift which is fast - see here (not the best example though) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850665/how-can-i-use-bit-shifting-to-replace-integer-division

Comment: FYI the equivalent function in ZF2 is basically the same as your second example. Like Lee McNeil said I think it was just down to personal choice by whoever wrote the ZF1 func.

Answer (score 2):

maybe because they just care for

**5** 03

**4** 04

**4** 01

**3** 02

**2** 01

and so on, the basicly are interested in the class of errortype not the specifics

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code I don't think there is any reasoning other than personal choice by the developer.